# Positional encodings and dropout

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden

In the current implementation of the transformer model, dropout is applied right after adding the positional encodings to the inputs, both in the encode and the decode functions. [relevant line in code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/transformer/transformer.py#L179)

Since kept features are re-scaled, doesn't that affect the structure of the underlying positional encodings ? Should the positional encodings be added *after* the dropout operation for correctness ?

**Model used**
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/transformer